# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.7.0:compile -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m -Xmx4096m -XX:-UseSplitVerifier -

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gwt

I would like to compile a GWT project in Eclipse.

I created the project using the gwt-maven-plugin archetype. My pom looks likt this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    eSWDES-Online
    war
    e-Surface Water Data Entry System

```
<properties>
    <!-- Convenience property to set the GWT version -->
    <gwtVersion>2.7.0</gwtVersion>
    <springVersion>3.2.3.RELEASE</springVersion>
    <!-- GWT needs at least java 1.5 -->
    <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</webappDirectory>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>eSWDESOnline</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <gwt.compile.module1>com.eptisati.eswis.eswdes.app.desktop.eSWDESDesktopOnline</gwt.compile.module1>
            <gwt.compile.module2>com.eptisati.eswis.eswdes.app.mobile.eSWDESMobile</gwt.compile.module2>
            <war.name>eSWDES</war.name>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <tasks>
                                    <!-- Deleting development workarea -->
                                    <delete file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/workareas.xml" />
                                    <!-- Copying the proper one -->
                                    <copy file="src/main/resources/workareas_pro.xml"
                                        tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/workareas.xml" />
                                    <!-- Deleting non used -->
                                    <delete file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/workareas_*.xml" />
                                </tasks>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>      
</profiles>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
        <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
        <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.eptisati.eswis</groupId>
        <artifactId>eSWDES-Controller</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.opengis</groupId>
                <artifactId>geoapi-nogenerics</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.gwtmodernizr</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwtmodernizr</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/gwt-user-libs/gwtmodernizr-1.0.1.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- IOC commons -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.seleniti.ioccommons</groupId>
        <artifactId>ioc-commons-gwt-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${ioc-commons-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.seleniti.ioccommons</groupId>
        <artifactId>ioc-commons</artifactId>
        <version>${ioc-commons-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.seleniti.ioccommons</groupId>
        <artifactId>ioc-commons-ext</artifactId>
        <version>${ioc-commons-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.seleniti.ioccommons</groupId>
        <artifactId>ioc-commons-utils</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <!-- <version>${ioc-commons-version}</version> -->
    </dependency>
    <!-- IOC commons extra -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.seleniti.ioccommons</groupId>
        <artifactId>ioccommons-extra-gwt-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>es.eptisati.mapviewer</groupId>
        <artifactId>MapController-Openlayers21Impl</artifactId>
        <version>${eptisa-mapviewer-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.mgwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>mgwt</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.gwtphonegap</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwtphonegap</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- ESRI -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.esri</groupId>
        <artifactId>jpe93_sdk</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/jpe93_sdk.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.esri</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsde93_sdk</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/jsde93_sdk.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <!-- Generate compiled stuff in the folder used for developing mode -->
    <outputDirectory>${webappDirectory}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>

        <!-- GWT Maven Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <!-- <goal>test</goal> <goal>i18n</goal> -->
                        <goal>generateAsync</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <!-- Plugin configuration. There are many available options, see gwt-maven-plugin 
                documentation at codehaus.org -->
            <configuration>
                <runTarget>eswdes-desktop.html</runTarget>
                <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>
                <!-- <i18nMessagesBundle>com.eptisati.eswis.esdes.app.online.client.Messages</i18nMessagesBundle> -->
                <enableClosureCompiler>true</enableClosureCompiler>
                <enableAssertions>true</enableAssertions>
                <extraJvmArgs>-XX:MaxPermSize=4096m -Xmx4096m -XX:-UseSplitVerifier</extraJvmArgs>
                <localWorkers>2</localWorkers>
                <modules>
                    <module>${gwt.compile.module1}</module>
                    <module>${gwt.compile.module2}</module>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>create</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <doCheck>true</doCheck>
                <doUpdate>true</doUpdate>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Copy static web files before executing gwt:run -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exploded</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <webappDirectory>${webappDirectory}</webappDirectory>
                <packagingExcludes>**/*.devmode.js</packagingExcludes>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Implementation-Build>${buildNumber}</Implementation-Build>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
                <warName>${war.name}</warName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <encoding>${mvn.project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <connectionType>connection</connectionType>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->                            
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-datanucleus-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.1.4,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>enhance</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-gae-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[0.7.3,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.apache.maven.plugins
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        maven-war-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [2.3,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>exploded</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                            <!-- <pluginExecution> <pluginExecutionFilter> <groupId> org.codehaus.mojo 
                                </groupId> <artifactId> gwt-maven-plugin </artifactId> <versionRange> [2.7.0,) 
                                </versionRange> <goals> <goal>i18n</goal> </goals> </pluginExecutionFilter> 
                                <action> <ignore></ignore> </action> </pluginExecution> -->
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.codehaus.mojo
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        exec-maven-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [1.2,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>exec</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>../${webappDirectory}/gwt-unitCache</directory>
                            <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                        </fileset>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp/eswdesdesktop</directory>
                        </fileset>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib</directory>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>gwt-unitCache</id>
                        <phase>clean</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>clean</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>sonatype-oss-public</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>       
</repositories>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.eptisati.eswis</groupId>
    <artifactId>eSWDES</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../eSWDES/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vividsolutions</groupId>
            <artifactId>jts</artifactId>
            <version>1.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```